# Haskell stack: How can I fix this connection timeout?

Tags: windows, haskell, haskell-stack

I have some downtime at work and would like to spend it getting familiar with Haskell.

I am trying a simple `HellowWorld.fs`, which works fine at home, but doesn't at work.

I have a 'developer' account with the ability to install software, and generally IT can be convinced to unblock various network restrictions, but I have to be able to describe exactly what needs to be unblocked.

Here is what I am seeing:

```
C:\WorkSpace>stack HelloWorld.hs
Downloading lts-13.7 build plan ...
RedownloadHttpError (HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "raw.githubusercontent.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = [("User-Agent","The Haskell Stack")]
  path                 = "/fpco/lts-haskell/master//lts-13.7.yaml"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 ConnectionTimeout)
Access violation in generated code when reading 00007ffc39deffff
```

This is from Windows 10 command prompt.

I can navigate just fine to [raw.githubusercontent.com/fpco/lts-haskell/master//lts-13.7.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fpco/lts-haskell/master//lts-13.7.yaml) from my browser. Is that even where the problem is in this case? How can I diagnose what the problem is and then communicate the solution to IT? Even better, how can I solve it without getting IT involved?

Comment: Do you have a proxy configured for your normal web access? Because it doesn't show one above

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no proxy configured. Also, check my update, I added some more information. HTTPS works, but HTTP does not. Can I get stack to use HTTPS?

Comment: Actually scratch my previous comment, don't know how I came up with that but HTTP does in fact work, even from Postman. I will revert my update.

Comment: As Richard wrote, please check in your browser if it has proxy enabled (auto?). If yes, you must configure stack to use it https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1673

Comment: The box next to "Use a proxy server for you LAN ..." is not checked. Is that conclusive proof in a work environment with a network management team?